The property afterSignInUrl does not work in Clerk
enter image description here
I have try to use the property afterSignInUrl="/learn" in my project but it doesn't work, the packages are installed and I've already searched the documentation, found nothing... I know it exists, but I'm not able to use it. If anyone can help, I appreciate it.
import Image from "next/image";
import { Loader } from "lucide-react";
import {
  ClerkLoaded,
  ClerkLoading,
  SignedIn,
  SignedOut,
  SignInButton,
  UserButton,
} from "@clerk/nextjs";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";

export const Header = () => {
  return (
    <header className="h-20 w-full border-b-2 
    border-slate-200 px-4">
      <div className="lg:max-w-screen-lg mx-auto flex items-center
      justify-between h-full">
        <div className="pt-8 pl-4 pb-7 flex items-center gap-x-3">
          <Image src="/mascot.svg" height={40} width={40} alt="Mascot" />
          <h1 className="text-2xl font-extrabold text-green-600 tracking-wide">
            Lingo
          </h1>
        </div>
        <ClerkLoading>
          <Loader className="h-5 w-5 text-muted-foreground animate-spin" />
        </ClerkLoading>
        <ClerkLoaded>
          <SignedIn>
            <UserButton
          afterSignOutUrl="/"
            />
          </SignedIn>
          <SignedOut>
            <SignInButton mode="modal"
            afterSignInUrl="/learn"
            afterSignUpUrl="/learn"
            >
            <Button size="lg" variant="ghost">
              Login
            </Button>
            </SignInButton>
          </SignedOut>
        </ClerkLoaded>
      </div>
    </header>
  );
};

I'm trying to make it so that after logging in, the user is redirected to the /learn page, but this isn't happening. I authenticate correctly and everything else, but I'm redirected back to the main page.

EDIT
You actually don't even need to force it, those are enough in your .env file:
NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_AFTER_SIGN_IN_URL=http://localhost:3000/learn
NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_AFTER_SIGN_UP_URL=http://localhost:3000/learn

Original answer
In the newest version of Clerk there's no afterSignInUrl property anymore. Following the docs (https://clerk.com/docs/components/unstyled/sign-in-button) the best thing to do is to add env variables (Clerk's team recommendation) or use forceRedirectUrl and optionally fallbackRedirectUrl prop to the SignInButton component.
Here you can check what env variables you need to add to make redirection work: https://clerk.com/docs/deployments/clerk-environment-variables#sign-in-and-sign-up-redirects

This works for me:
add in the .env
NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_SIGN_IN_FORCE_REDIRECT_URL="http://localhost:3000/learn"
NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_SIGN_UP_FORCE_REDIRECT_URL="http://localhost:3000/learn"

